# How to post an uploaded photo to wall?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I post an uploaded photo to a user's wall/feed?

My application generates an image with the name of the user and some information. It looks like a certificate. I upload this image to the user's profile, but it doesn't appears on the feed. So the friends don't see that. I tried to post it with -

```
$post = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', array(...));
```

But I realized, that I can't post Facebook hosted photos. But there are many applications on Facebook that generate images, uploads them and posts them to a wall. But how?

Comment: You have no control over what appears in **other** user's feeds.  Facebook decides what to show you on the homepage.  If the users were to go into the users **profile** they would see the uploaded image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post facebook-hosted pictures onto the user's wall. You need to do a simple wall post, and include the `object_attachment` parameter, which contains the picture's id. It is documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts), near the bottom of the table.

You can find more details in [this](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/526/) blogpost. It also contains the following example:

```
<?php
  $app_id = "APP_ID";
  $app_secret = "APP_SECRET";
  $post_login_url = "POST_AUTH_REDIRECT_URL";
  $photo_id = "PHOTO_ID";
  $wall_message = "MESSAGE_FOR_POST";
  $wall_link = "LINK_TO_POST";
  $user_id = "USER_ID";

  $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

  // Obtain the access_token with publish_stream permission 
  if (!$code) {
    $dialog_url= "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"
      . "client_id=" .  $app_id
      . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
      .  "&scope=publish_stream";
    echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url
      . "'</script>");
  } else {
    $token_url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
      . "client_id=" . $app_id
      . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
      . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
      . "&code=" . $code;
    $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
    $params = null;
    parse_str($response, $params);
    $access_token = $params['access_token'];

    // POST to Graph API feed endpoint, which is the user's Wall
    $graph_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/" . $user_id . "/feed?"
      . "message=" . urlencode($wall_message)
      . "&link=" . urlencode($wall_link)
      . "&object_attachment=" . $photo_id
      . "&method=POST"
      . "&access_token=" .$access_token;

    echo '<html><body>';
    echo file_get_contents($graph_url);
    echo '</body></html>';
  }
?>
```

Comment: Ok, it's work, but the size of the photo is small in the post. And the other applications are posting in large size. How can I set this?

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't figured out that yet.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you can not post a Facebook hosted image back to Facebook.  As I see it, you have two options.

1. Download the image to *your* server and upload it again to the users feed.
2. Simply post a link to that photo_object on the users feed.  Facebook's crawlers will successfully extract the relevant data from that link and you'll still get a preview of the image in the post.

When you query the Graph API with a photo_id -
example - https://graph.facebook.com/10151812415573306 (a public photo on [CocaCola's page](https://www.facebook.com/cocacola)), you get some information about that image.  The data looks something like this -

```
    {
      "id": "10151812415573306", 
      "from": {
        "name": "Coca-Cola", 
        "category": "Food/beverages", 
        "id": "40796308305"
      }, 
      "picture": "https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/521913_10151812415573306_523748375_s.jpg", 
      "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/521913_10151812415573306_523748375_n.jpg", 
      "height": 332, 
      "width": 500, 
       ...
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151812415573306&set=a.99394368305.88399.40796308305&type=1", 
      "icon": "https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v2/yz/r/StEh3RhPvjk.gif", 
      "created_time": "2012-07-09T12:00:41+0000", 
      ...
```

The parameter you need to post on the users feed is the `link` parameter -
`https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151812415573306&set=a.99394368305.88399.40796308305&type=1`

When you post that URL on a users feed/wall - the post will contain a preview of the image and a link to the photo itself (within Facebook).